# Getting "Cannot read property 'pickAlgorithm' of null" error in react native

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

I get an error when running `npm install`.
The error is:

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'pickAlgorithm' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!    npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-14T08_03_47_266Z-debug.log
```

I did the following but the error stays:

1. Deleted `node-modules`
2. Deleted the given file
3. Running `npm cache clear --force`

**Environment:**

OS: Windows 10
react native: 0.65.1
Node: 14.17.4
npm: 7.21.0

Comment: Why is there so many duplicate answers on this (legitimate) question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Upgraded to npm v7.23.0 and then `npm install` so it's working fine now.

Answer (score 264):

The only thing that helped me was clearing cache:

```
npm cache clear --force
```

Comment: this works, but I'm having to do this repeatedly now, any one know how to keep this from happening for good??

Answer (score 56):

please use following:

```
npm cache clear --force

npm install
```

in my case it is working

Answer (score 27):

For me, the error came up while I was trying to work with the json-server module. And clearing the cache worked for me

```
npm cache clear --force
```

Afterwards, reinstall/update your mode modules

```
npm install
```

If that doesn't work, try reseting you npm config:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 15):

It seems that running

```
npm cache clear --force
```

Is what worked and recommended by everyone. Unfortunately, it did not work for me. There were other suggestions to save-dev first. This also did not work for me.

What I did in order to overcome this issue myself, was narrowing my package.json dependencies. I removed all of them, and kept returning them incrementally until I found the dependency that was causing the issue. I updated the dependency version, and this was what I needed to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 12):

Running this worked for me

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Answer (score 5):

if you are using Windows OS, close VS Code then open command prompt as administrator and run `npm cache verify` and `npm install`

it works for me

Answer (score 5):

In my case we had an old package-lock.json that caused these issues. Regenerating package-lock.json fixed the issue. To do this delete package-lock.json and then run npm install

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1: Cache Clear**

First, run this command:- `npm cache clear --force`

Then run this command:- `npm install`

**Solution 2: set npm config**

You need to set npm config registry just like this.

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

We can also run npm install with registry options for multiple custom registry URLs.

```
npm install --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/ 
npm install --registry=https://custom.npm.registry.com/
```

Answer (score 2):

First run `npm cache clear --force` and then close VPN. It worked for me (in China)

Answer (score 1):

One of the packages was deprecated.
I started in new folder a test project and then copied some of the packages to this tested project until found the problematic package.

create on new folder a test-project and open cmd in this location.

> npm init -y // creates  package.json with defaults
> copy to depencencies / devdependencies in  that package.json packeges from the origin project.
> npm i

Answer (score 1):

My problem was because the wifi adaptor of my PC was very inconsistent and would give network errors often, giving the error mentioned, among others, when trying to install bigger packages (in my case, expo). What helped in my case was tethering my android phone to PC and using the connection that way.

This link helped me getting it done: https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/2812516

Answer (score 1):

If these solutions didn't work,

```
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Then this will definitely work!

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

After executing the above command,

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

I completely deleted nodejs and then reinstalled version 16 of it.

The following links are helpful:

- [How To Install Node.js in Linux Mint 20 - TechViewLeo](https://techviewleo.com/how-to-install-nodejs-in-linux-mint/)
- [How can you completely remove a package? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151941/how-can-you-completely-remove-a-package)

Answer (score 0):

Use
npm upgrade npm
to get the latest version of npm

Answer (score 0):

1 liner shortcut

```
npm cache clear -f && npm i
```

Answer (score -1):

i was try this step to solve that problem:

1. close VS Code
2. Run from CMD
3. `npm cache clear --force`
4. `npm cache verify`
5. `npm install -g create-react-app`

Answer (score -1):

1. close VS code،
2. Install last version Node
3. CMD : `npm install -g create-react-app`
4. `npm cache clear --force`
5. `npx create-react-app <projectName>`

Or Reinstall node

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).