# I keep on getting this error when installing @mui/icons-material

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'pickAlgorithm' of null

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-02T04_49_26_513Z-debug.log

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69567381/9449426) question?

Answer (score 0):

delete your `package-lock.json` and install `icons-material` and `material` packages:

```
npm install @mui/icons-material @mui/material
```