# npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')

Tags: node.js, npm

iam getting below error with npm while creating react app

npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Nagamanickam\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-11-18T12_01_45_525Z-debug.log

Comment: Well could you add a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "Cannot read property 'pickAlgorithm' of null" error in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69567381/getting-cannot-read-property-pickalgorithm-of-null-error-in-react-native)

Comment: ere is something very similar asked before: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69567381/getting-cannot-read-property-pickalgorithm-of-null-error-in-react-native)

Answer (score 22):

I resolved it by deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` again.

Comment: didn't solve it for me

Comment: Didn't work for me too

Comment: Problem for me was in Jenkins Builds only, local builds were successful. The cause was that we do commit package-lock.json. In the build Jenkins appends the build-no to version in package.json. This way package.json and package-lock.json were inconsistent and npm install failed. The solution was to delete package-lock.json prior to npm install.

Answer (score 18):

my npm version is 8.1.4 and i solve this **problem** by running :

> npm cache clear --force

Comment: didn't solve it for me

Comment: Didn't work for me too

Comment: Did not work for me as well

Comment: Didn't work for me either

Comment: Fixed it for me!

Answer (score 13):

solved with `npm i  --legacy-peer-deps` on react-native version .70

Answer (score 8):

Just run these 2 commands :

```
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Probably it's a project that works with Yarn and not NPM.
Try Yarn instead of NPM.

```
yarn install
```

and then you can do

```
yarn start
```

or

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 3):

Your dependency tree may be broken (due to incompartible peer dependencies) you can try running npm install with `--legacy-peer-deps` or `--force` to bypass this issue for the mean time.

Answer (score 3):

In my case i updated npm via:

```
npm update -g npm
```

After it, everything worked fine.

Don't know why, i didn't expect it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have this issue on the CI:

```
$ npm ci
npm ERR! Cannot read property '<any-package-here>' of undefined
```

You should check the version of Nodeon the CI. It was outdated for me.

Comment: This saved my time. I found that I used the version of Node which isn't matched with the requirement in the package.json.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the file .npmrc was corrupt. After deleting it everything worked.

Comment: where .npmrc can be found?

Comment: In your home directory

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, but I was able to resolve it by the below described method:

Go to folder -> Local > npm-cache and delete all contents of the npm-cache.
try again with npm command, it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by update npm from 6.x to 8.5x, then run npm cache clear --force, npm install, however, it has to change the nodejs from 14 to 17, my env is macOS m1 pro.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error from an old branch that had a previous version of node/npm. using the correct version of node helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you were encountering this problem while using NPM workspaces, try removing all of the node_modules directory that is not the root one. Such as:

```bash
$ rm -rf packages/*/node_modules
$ npm install
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved deleting `node_modules` and running this command:

> npm cache clear --force