# How to read properties of null?

Tags: reactjs, null, dependencies, npm-install, styled-components

In Reactjs, while running npm install, styled-components display an error. While installing other dependencies is working fine, the problem is with styled-components.

```
npm ERR! cannot read the properties of null (read "edgesOut").
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:UsersDELLAppDataLocalnpm-cache_logs2023-05-09T07_37_18_586Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70019872/npm-err-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-pickalgorithm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also have run into this issue.

Using

```bash
npm install styled-components@5.3.10
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me. I instead google searched npm styled-components and found that this worked for me:

```
npm install styled-components@^5.0.0 react@^16.8 react-dom@^16.8 react-is@^16.8
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem, version 5.3.10 was not installed either.
Helped:

1. delete folder node_modules
2. delete package-lock.json
3. `npm i styled-components@latest` or `npm i styled-components@5.3.10` or `npm i styled-components`. Which one do you want.
4. install all other packages `npm i`