# Why does my terminal keep Flagging error while creating my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have been trying to create my first React App for a while now and it has been flagging me different errors.
This is the code I typed in my Hyper terminal: "npx create-react-app app".
After trying to download for some minutes it would then flag the error below:

**Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Edmund Obinna\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-22T11_18_49_833Z-debug-0.log
Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting app/ from C:\Users\Edmund Obinna
Done.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "Cannot read property 'pickAlgorithm' of null" error in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69567381/getting-cannot-read-property-pickalgorithm-of-null-error-in-react-native)