# /node_modules/canvas: Command failed. Exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, npm

I run the same code on a linux based system and it works just fine. I am using an M1 Mac

This error appears when i run yarn

````
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/drou/.npm/_logs/2022-09-03T23_15_56_683Z-debug-0.log
drou@Alexandross-MacBook-Air hashlips_art_engine % sudo npm install
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'pickAlgorithm')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/drou/.npm/_logs/2022-09-03T23_16_13_795Z-debug-0.log```
````

Comment: When does this error appear?

Comment: When i run yarn.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69567381/getting-cannot-read-property-pickalgorithm-of-null-error-in-react-native are you moving around node_modules, package-lock.json between OS types?

Comment: Nope. I simply bring the code without the dependencies

Answer (score 1):

First Try installing the binaries for canvas mentioned in `https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas`

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev
```

Then install canvas:

```
npm install canvas
```

Comment: for mac user
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg